# Why order matters for multiindex selection using .ix

Tags: python-2.7, indexing, pandas, dataframe

Still trying to understand multi-index selection.  Building the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import *

arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
          ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'],
          ['cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'dog', 'dog']]

tuples = zip(*arrays)
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first','second','third'])
data = pd.DataFrame(random.randn(8,3), index=index, columns=['c1','c2','c3'])

>>> data
                          c1        c2        c3
first second third                              
bar   one    cat   -0.309651 -0.242866  0.824422
      two    cat   -0.349640  0.873796 -1.879832
baz   one    cat   -0.851390 -1.241419 -0.016495
      two    cat    0.737211 -0.617967 -2.215459
foo   one    dog   -0.231820  0.140641 -1.619270
      two    dog   -1.363132 -0.929765 -0.005083
qux   one    dog   -1.187903 -0.753883 -0.442464
      two    dog    0.652967  0.423994 -0.705735
```

***Question 1:*** If I want to change "c1" values to c1*10, can I do this as is?  I have tried

```
data.ix['cat'].c1 = data.ix['cat'].c1*10
# Also tried 
data.xs('cat',level='second').c1 = data.xs('cat',level='second').c1*10
```

neither of which worked.  I get a "KeyError" for the first and

"TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '**getitem**' " for the second

***Confusing solution***

I found a solution in reordering the index, but this has strange behavior (at least strange to me).

```
d = data.copy() 
d.index = d.index.reorder_levels( [2,0,1] )
>>> d
                          c1        c2        c3
third first second                              
cat   bar   one    -0.309651 -0.242866  0.824422
            two    -0.349640  0.873796 -1.879832
      baz   one    -0.851390 -1.241419 -0.016495
            two     0.737211 -0.617967 -2.215459
dog   foo   one    -0.231820  0.140641 -1.619270
            two    -1.363132 -0.929765 -0.005083
      qux   one    -1.187903 -0.753883 -0.442464
            two     0.652967  0.423994 -0.705735


# Now perform the operation (use *NaN below to make changes easily distinguished)
d.ix['cat'].c1 = d.ix['cat'].c1*NaN

>>> d
                          c1        c2        c3
third first second                              
cat   bar   one          NaN -0.242866  0.824422
            two          NaN  0.873796 -1.879832
      baz   one          NaN -1.241419 -0.016495
            two          NaN -0.617967 -2.215459
dog   foo   one    -0.231820  0.140641 -1.619270
            two    -1.363132 -0.929765 -0.005083
      qux   one    -1.187903 -0.753883 -0.442464
            two     0.652967  0.423994 -0.705735
```

Great!  That worked.  But what if I watned to make "second" the first index?

```
d = data.copy()
d.index = d.index.reorder_levels( [1,0,2] )
>>> d
                          c1        c2        c3
second first third                              
one    bar   cat   -0.309651 -0.242866  0.824422
two    bar   cat   -0.349640  0.873796 -1.879832
one    baz   cat   -0.851390 -1.241419 -0.016495
two    baz   cat    0.737211 -0.617967 -2.215459
one    foo   dog   -0.231820  0.140641 -1.619270
two    foo   dog   -1.363132 -0.929765 -0.005083
one    qux   dog   -1.187903 -0.753883 -0.442464
two    qux   dog    0.652967  0.423994 -0.705735

# Using the same logic as above...
d.ix['two'].c1 = d.ix['two'].c1*NaN

>>>                          c1        c2        c3
second first third                              
one    bar   cat   -0.309651 -0.242866  0.824422
two    bar   cat   -0.349640  0.873796 -1.879832
one    baz   cat   -0.851390 -1.241419 -0.016495
two    baz   cat    0.737211 -0.617967 -2.215459
one    foo   dog   -0.231820  0.140641 -1.619270
two    foo   dog   -1.363132 -0.929765 -0.005083
one    qux   dog   -1.187903 -0.753883 -0.442464
two    qux   dog    0.652967  0.423994 -0.705735
```

No change!  But this (below) does work

```
# Keeping same data frame from previous example
d.c1.ix['two'] = d.ix['two'].c1*NaN

>>> d
                          c1        c2        c3
second first third                              
one    bar   cat   -0.309651 -0.242866  0.824422
two    bar   cat         NaN  0.873796 -1.879832
one    baz   cat   -0.851390 -1.241419 -0.016495
two    baz   cat         NaN -0.617967 -2.215459
one    foo   dog   -0.231820  0.140641 -1.619270
two    foo   dog         NaN -0.929765 -0.005083
one    qux   dog   -1.187903 -0.753883 -0.442464
two    qux   dog         NaN  0.423994 -0.705735
```

***Question 2:*** I don't understand why the order of d.ix['ID'].c1 vs d.c1.ix['ID'] matters depending on how the dataframe's index levels are ordered.  Does this make sense to anyone else?  If it does, can you explain what is going on here?  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: read this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy. use ``df.loc[row,column] = value`` to ensure you are setting the actual object

Comment: so you just want to change a sub-frame, e.g. a certain column indexed by a certain level? or all of the column ``c1``?

Comment: Just wanting to change a sub-frame.

Answer (score 2):

Your data

```
In [48]: data = pd.DataFrame(random.randn(8,3), index=index, columns=['c1','c2','c3'])

In [49]: data
Out[49]: 
                          c1        c2        c3
first second third                              
bar   one    cat    0.219103 -1.142457  0.045307
      two    cat    0.890187  1.097527  0.074196
baz   one    cat   -0.043345 -0.595815  0.775877
      two    cat   -0.694324 -0.757964 -1.253632
foo   one    dog   -2.182311  0.474872  1.444720
      two    dog    1.482957 -0.658113  0.743051
qux   one    dog    1.544032 -0.225756  0.821863
      two    dog    0.121410 -0.143425  1.157422

[8 rows x 3 columns]
```

Compose a mask of the values that you want to change (could be more complicated
or even be manual here); you need a boolean for EACH index though (e.g. has to be the same length as the length of the frame)

```
In [50]: mask = data.index.get_level_values('third') == 'cat'

In [51]: mask
Out[51]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Directly index

```
In [52]: data.loc[mask,'c1'] *= 10

In [53]: data
Out[53]: 
                          c1        c2        c3
first second third                              
bar   one    cat    2.191029 -1.142457  0.045307
      two    cat    8.901870  1.097527  0.074196
baz   one    cat   -0.433448 -0.595815  0.775877
      two    cat   -6.943241 -0.757964 -1.253632
foo   one    dog   -2.182311  0.474872  1.444720
      two    dog    1.482957 -0.658113  0.743051
qux   one    dog    1.544032 -0.225756  0.821863
      two    dog    0.121410 -0.143425  1.157422

[8 rows x 3 columns]
```